# keyboard input doesnt work in libgdx android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've has this problem for about 2 weeks now. Im making a text based game which requires you to type. However, i am using my own input system, rather than LIBGDX's textfields, long story. Basically what i need is

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.a)){
      //do some stuff
   }
```

that. However this doesn't work on android, works fine on desktop though. I'm not sure why this is, its starting to annoy me. One thing i have found is that if you continuously press a key on android it eventually types it but this makes game play extremely tedious. I have also tried using an InputProcessor but this doesn't work either. Ive now tried practically everything i can think of without a solution. Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT 1:

i have also tried InputProcessor. the thing with this is, it doesnt do anything on key press but then when i press Androids hardware back, it does what it should have done when the key was originally pressed. Also with both methods i find that it works with some keyboards not others. EG: works with HTC sense keyboard

EDIT 2:
With a bit more fiddling round i found that if i get the app to do something under the keyIsTyped method of InputProcessor it does it only after the keyboard is closed. not sure if this means anything

Answer (score 1):

You're doing polling-based input, and I think you would be better served by an event-based structure.  With polling you only find out if the key was pressed if you happen to check it while it is pressed (which is based on the refresh rate), with event-based you will receive an event for every keypress that happens, whenever it happens, and no matter how quick it is.

See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

If you're having problems with getting keyboard events that way, please post another question!

Comment: He wrote "I have also tried using an InputProcessor but this doesn't work either."

Comment: Yeah, I know, but there is no detail.  He could edit this question to cover both ways of getting input, but I suspect the answers are very different, so it seems like it should be a new question ...

Comment: Yes but that if is in render, so its contantly checking. works fine on dekstop. also i have tried InputProcessor. Ive added to question